# Storing for loop value in specific variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

so I've this shell script, where i take simple user input of IPs and store that into a text file.

```
MasterNode(){
echo "Enter number of Master Node below"
read -r numESM

for ((i=1; i<=${numESM}; i++))
  do
    echo "${bold}Enter Master node server IP below${normal}"
    read IPS;
    echo "${IPS}" >> /path/Master.txt 2>&1
done
}
MasterNode
```

Master.txt output is this

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.1
1.1.2.1
```

and i want to save these IPs in this format into another file (configuration) file

```
discovery.seed_hosts: ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.1","1.1.2.1"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.1"]
```

Is there any way by which I can store each value which I get in the loop into some dynamic variable like, when the loop runs first the value is stored in A[0] and A[0] have value 1.1.1.1
similarly A[1] which have value 2.2.2.1. then getting its value just like any other vairable in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
echo "Enter number of Master Node below"
read -r numESM

IPS=() # make empty array
for ((i=1; i<=${numESM}; i++))
do
    echo "Enter Master node server IP below"
    read IP;
    IPS+=($IP) # add entry to array
done

line="discovery.seed_hosts: ["
for i in "${IPS[@]}"
do
    line="${line}\"${i}\"," # add entry to line
done

line="${line%?}" # remove last ","
line="${line}]"  # add "]"
echo $line
```

You know how to put that into your function, right? Another way would be to add entries to the `line` as they are entered and get rid of one `for` loop. However, you have more possibilities how to add them, and which to add to a line in another `for` loop. Here is it with one `for` loop:

```
echo "Enter number of Master Node below"
read -r numESM

line="discovery.seed_hosts: ["
for ((i=1; i<=${numESM}; i++))
do
    echo "Enter Master node server IP below"
    read IP;
    line="${line}\"${IP}\","
done

line="${line%?}" # remove last ","
line="${line}]"  # add "]"
echo $line
```

Warning: It does not work properly for 0 entries.

Comment: @noody this is exactly what I was looking for... thank you so much. really appreciate your help

Comment: Make sure you **always** keep the variables quoted: `IPS+=("$IP")` -- there's no telling what a user will enter that can trip you up.